# Computer resources used in the morning

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, memory-usage

I have a Dell Optiplex Windows 10 computer with 4GB of ram. running a private ssh server (latest SSH server built in to windows). It runs really well and quick for the most part, until the next morning. When I wake up in the morning the cpu is at 99%, and I only have 300/4,000 or so MB of ram left. What’s really weird is that my process monitor says that the program using the highest cpu is only using 1% of the cpu (just like it normally would), and the program using the most ram is only using 400MB (this morning it was the powershell ISE I left open the day before).

The only way to fix it is by ordering a restart from ssh, which takes about 30 seconds to issue each command, including connecting and logging in. RDP won’t even work. It takes about a minute to “connect” but then it’s just a screen of frozen colorful static.

A restart fixes the problem but obviously this is not ideal.

My main question is what is causing the CPU and RAM to be used but not show up on any task managers?

Update: I noticed that even though the CPU is at "100%", the fan isn't even on and the computer isn't hot. This lead me to think I might have a memory leak in one of my scripts, which I had never experienced before. I disabled a couple of them and to my surprise the system is working well this morning. Now I'll start enabling them one at a time until I figure out which it is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I restarted the question if that helps...

Comment: You don’t indicate what version of Windows.  You don’t indicate what version of OpenSSH your using (or whatever your using for the SSH functionality)

Comment: Latest ssh, and I labeled it in the tags for Windows. Try reading everything.

Comment: Please be specific.  "Latest SSH" means two different things, the reason I say that is if your using the built-in OpenSSH functionality that is one version if you installed OpenSSH that is an entirely different version.  What version of Windows 10 are you using?